# Move google map center javascript api

Tags: javascript, maps

In my  project I want to move the center of the map to new coordinates. This is the code I have for the map

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  function moveToLocation(lat, lng){
     var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     var map = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
     map.panTo(center);

  }
```

The moveToLocation function does get called but the map does not re center. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Your problem is that in `moveToLocation`, you're using `document.getElementById` to try to get the `Map` object, but that only gets you an `HTMLDivElement`, not the `google.maps.Map` object you're expecting.  So your variable `map` has no `panTo` function, which is why it doesn't work.  What you need to is squirrel the `map` variable away somewhere, and it should work as planned.  You can just use a global variable like so:

```
window.map = undefined;      // global variable

function initialize() {
  const mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  // assigning to global variable:
  window.map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function moveToLocation(lat, lng){
  const center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  // using global variable:
  window.map.panTo(center);
}
```

See working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fqt7L/1/

Answer (score 1):

Display the Google Maps API using dynamically, fetch the data in database to display the place, lat, long and to show map marker in center using AngularJS. Done by Sureshchan...

[image: Screenshot of Google Maps]

```
$(function() {
    $http.get('school/transport/scroute/viewRoute?scRouteId=' + scRouteId).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.viewRoute.length; i++) {
            $scope.view = [];
            $scope.view.push(data.viewRoute[i].stoppingName, data.viewRoute[i].latitude, data.viewRoute[i].longitude);
            $scope.locData.push($scope.view);
        }            

        var locations = $scope.locData;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {                    
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var marker, j;

        for (j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(locations[j][1], locations[j][2]),
                map : map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, j) {
                bounds.extend(marker.position);
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[j][0]); 
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
                    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                }
            })(marker, j));
        };
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a 4 year old question with accepted answer.

Comment: Not really sure what value this has when the original answer is much more simple to implement.