# how to do auto center and set bound automatically with dynamically generated marker for google map?

Tags: php, mysql, api, google-maps

I have tried pretty much all the codes I can get on this site, and none of the has worked. Here is the original code I got from google map API for generating markers. I want the map to set the bound and center automatically based on the locations of the markers.

Please help me with the code and kindly inform me where to put the code exactly.

Thanks.

```
<script>
  var customLabel = {
    restaurant: {
      label: 'R'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'B'
    }
  };

    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      zoom: 12

    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('http://localhost/test/mapxml.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label,
          });

          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          }); 

          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          bounds.extend(myLatLng);
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
          map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());



        });//marker



      });//download xml 



    }//initMap



  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

Comment: What is your CSS for the tag `id="map"`.

Comment: #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

Comment: This question may help you... [Move google map center javascript api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699300/move-google-map-center-javascript-api) Best of luck...

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps V3 API - Center on a category pulling from xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121240/google-maps-v3-api-center-on-a-category-pulling-from-xml-file)